# Excel: How to search for substring from a column in another column

Tags: excel, search, substring

This may have been been asked before (I found an answer for SQL, but not for Excel) and I am not sure how to search for it further. I want to find, for each row, if the string in Column1 is a part of Column2. Ideally I would get a Yes/No in a Column 3 if there is a match.

Basically, if the string in A1 is part of the string in B1, and so on for the rest of the column.

[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SEARCH, which will return a number if found:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," & A1 & ",","," & B1 & ",")),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try with a first element? E.g. put "1" in cell A1.

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering. My Excel is with ";" as a separator, thus I decided to ask in stead of trying :)

Comment: @Scott Craner The formula you described seems to do exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately, when I paste it into Excel, doesn't return anything. Should I do something more? (maybe I should mention I am using Excel 2010).

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't return anything.  it should return something, an error, Yes, or No. @TatianaR

Comment: I apologise, I meant it returns an error and after I hit OK, it highlights this part: ",",","

Comment: Do you use `;` instead of `,` to delineate the Criteria of the formula?  If so replace the `,` that are not inside the `""`.  `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," & A1 & ",";"," & B1 & ",")),"Yes";"No")`  Do not copy and paste from the comments.  They are known to cause errors.  Fix the commas manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

`=IF(ISERROR(FIND(A2,B2,1)),"No","Yes")`

Comment: This will find false positives.  If A1 is `1` and B1 is `10,12,17,19` it will return true.  When it should be false.

Comment: I understand the issue but he didn't mention the sub-strings were delimited by the commas (hence "bottle" and "can" being included). If that's what he meant then yes, it would cause false positives

Comment: That is true, I assumed OP meant full string delimited by columns.